# Replacing "NA" with a zero - SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Having more trouble with this than I could have imagined...

I have columns of numerical data, e.g statistics. Some rows in the columns say "NA" and I would like to replace these with zeros or NULL. This is possible, right?!

I tried REPLACE and it made everything NULL,

[image: REPLACE]

COALESCE, which still returned NA values...

[image: COALESCE]

I have read at least a dozen other posts but either they're slightly different cases or I'm just not getting it.

Best,
Wesley

Comment: Use NULL instead for missing values. Will not mess up AVG, MIN etc.

Comment: Do you store numerical data in character columns?!? Don't do that, use a proper numerical data type instead.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: I have edited the post to include screenshots of the code and results. I like @jarlh feedback to use null instead of Zero so the computations work.

Answer (score 1):

> I like @jarlh feedback to use ***null*** instead of Zero so the computations work.

In order to use `sg_putt` in the computations, it should be casted as *float type*. If so, below would be enough since it returns ***null*** if a value is not a valid float literal including `"NA"`.

```sql
SELECT SAFE_CAST(sg_putt AS FLOAT64) AS sg_putt
```

For example,

```sql
SELECT SAFE_CAST('-1.49' AS FLOAT64), SAFE_CAST('NA' AS FLOAT64);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE returns the first non-null argument, and 'NA' is non-null, so `COALESCE('NA', 'NA', NULL)` will always return 'NA'.

REPLACE should be used like `REPLACE(original_value, from_value, to_value)` so in your case: `REPLACE(sg_putt, 'NA', NULL)`

If that doesn't fix your problem, try a CASE statement instead:

```
SELECT
    CASE sg_putt
        WHEN 'NA' THEN NULL
        ELSE sg_putt
    END AS sg_putt_fixed
FROM
    ...
```